# Page navigation can't find page 2

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I don't know why does page navigation [do not work correctly](http://www.wapsmag.com/archives/category/contributors/w15).

There are more than 8 postings, but it shows just 8 postings. And I can't find page number '2' and the text 'next page'. Why?

```
<script>
$(".m7").show();
</script><div class="ppddff" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; margin-bottom:2px;">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>

<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.wapsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/blog_th.jpg" />

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ko_KR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<style>
.blttl a{ font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo','NanumMyeongjoExtraboldWeb', 맑은 고딕; color:#000;}
.blttl a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:#000;}
.tagstyle a{ font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo','NanumMyeongjoWeb', 맑은 고딕; color:#000;}
.tagstyle a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:#000;}
.ttop { background-color:black;}
.pagg{padding-top:100px; padding-bottom:0px;}
.catttl a { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;} 
.catttl a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
.ttyyuu a { color:#000000; text-decoration:none; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;} 
.ttyyuu a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
.subm a { margin:0 5px 0 5px; color:#666; text-decoration:none; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;} 
.subm a:hover { color:#000000; text-decoration:underline;}
.cover1 { display:none;}
</style>

<div style="width:100%; position:relative; overflow:hidden;">

<div style="width:900px; margin:20px auto; ">
<div style="padding-bottom:20px; margin-bottom:20px; border-bottom:1px solid #666;">
<div style="width:150px; height:210px; float:left; margin-top:10px; margin-right:20px; position:relative;"><?php ciii_category_images(""); ?></div>
<div style="width:730px; height:210px; float:left;">
<div class="blttl fvb" style="font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo','NanumMyeongjoExtraboldWeb', 맑은 고딕, 'Georgia'; font-size:16pt; color:#000; padding-top:10px; margin-bottom:3px; text-align:left;" ><?php single_cat_title(); ?> </div> 
<div style="font-size:10pt; color:#999; text-align:left; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; "class="ttyyuu"> <?php echo category_description( ); ?> 


</div>
<div style="width:900px; margin:10px auto; position:relative; height:30px; text-align:center;">
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " style="text-align:center; padding-left:0px;">
<a class="addthis_button_favorites"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-505280914104c869"></script>
<script>$(".addthis_button_tweet").css("width","90"); </script>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>


<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



<div style="width:900px; margin:0 auto;">
<div style="width:900px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:16pt; color:#000; font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo','NanumMyeongjoExtraBoldWeb', 

맑은 고딕;"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div style="width:900px; text-align:center; font-size:9pt; color:#999999; font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo','NanumMyeongjoWeb', 맑은 고딕;"><?php the_time(); ?></div>
<div style="width:900px; margin:0 auto; line-height:1.8em; font-size:10pt; color:#666666; font-family: 'Nanum Gothic','NanumGothicWeb', 맑은 고딕; padding-bottom:30px;"><?php 

the_content(); ?>

</div>
<div style="width:900px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; border-top:1px solid #CCC; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; ">
<div style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:12pt; color:#000000; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:left;">Tag <img src="/tagg.jpg" /></div>
<div class="tagstyle" style="font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo','NanumMyeongjoWeb', 맑은 고딕, 'Georgia'; font-size:10pt; color:#000; text-align:left;"><?php the_tags( '<div 

class="tagstyle">', ', ', '</div>'); ?></div>
</div><div style="height:0px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="blttl fvb" style="font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo','NanumMyeongjoExtraboldWeb', 맑은 고딕, 'Gerogia'; font-size:16pt; color:#000; padding-top:10px; margin-bottom:3px; text-

align:left;" >


</div></div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<div style="clear:both;">
</div>
</div>



<div style="padding-top:30px; border-top:1px solid black; width:900px; margin:0 auto;"><?php query_posts(array(
    'showposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'category_name' => 'sbanner' //You can insert any category name
));
 ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true) ?>" target="_new"/> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
          <?php endwhile; endif; ?></div>
    </div>






<div class="navvi" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:40px; width:900px; margin:0 auto;"><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></div>
<?php else : if ( is_category() ) { printf("<div class='center sorry' style='padding:150px 0 150px 0;'>Sorry, but there aren't any posts in the %s category yet.</div>", single_cat_title

('',false));} endif; ?>

</div>
<style>.sorry {font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo','NanumMyeongjoWeb', 맑은 고딕; font-size:12pt;}
.navvi a { color:#666666;}
.navvi a:hover { color:#000000; text-decoration:underline;}
</style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a second post query in your page, before calling the pagination plugin so it use this query to display pages, not the first/main one.

```
<div style="padding-top:30px; border-top:1px solid black; width:900px; margin:0 auto;">
<?php query_posts(array(
    'showposts' => 1, 
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'category_name' => 'sbanner' //You can insert any category name
));
 ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url', true) ?>" target="_new"/> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
          <?php endwhile; endif; ?></div>
    </div>
```

Before the second query, get the value of `wp_pagenavi()` (check this to learn how to do it : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-pagenavi-returning-a-string-not-printing-it-directly)

Then echo this value where you actually call `wp_pagenavi()`;